# how to refresh future builder when there is no obs variable inside in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am facing a problem in my current project for rebuilding future builder whenever data is added or updated..

after adding a number into numbers, future builder should be rebuild to show all updated numbers..

i have wrapped Future builder inside Obx but its not rebuilding as it does not contain any obs variable inside it...

So how to refresh it..on adding or deleting number

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.put(DataController());
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child:  Obx(
                ()=>FutureBuilder(
               future: controller.fetchData(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      const loader = Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                        return loader;

                      if (!snapshot.hasData ||
                          snapshot.data == null ||
                          snapshot.data!.isEmpty)
                        return Center(
                          child: Text('No data found'),
                        );

                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return const Center(
                          child: Text('Error found'),
                        );
                      }

                      final allData = snapshot.data!;

                      return ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: allData.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            final data = allData[index];
                            return ListTile(
                              title: Text(data.toString()),
                            );
                          });
                    })
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
                final num=Random().nextInt(1000);
                numbers.add(num);
              },child: Text('Add Number'),))
        ],
      ),

    );
  }
```

data controller

```
class DataController extends GetxController {
  RxBool isLoading = false.obs;
 

  Future<List<int>> fetchData() async {
    try {
      isLoading.value = true;
      final data = numbers;//numbers is a list[int] stored in different file
      return data;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Something wrong');
      return [];
    } finally {
      isLoading.value = false;
    }
  }
}
```

for data source
i have just created a list of int in a sepearate file

```
List<int> numbers=[1,2,3];
```

Comment: if you want multiple rebuilds then use `StreamBuilder`, not `FutureBuilder` - more on streams here: https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams

Comment: this is creating just a demo code what i actually looking for, i dont need multiple rebuilds...like in shopping app, adding user's addresses

Comment: reassign the `future` with setState, it will recall the app, obs isnt needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to me you have 3 options to solve your problem but it depend on your code which is ok for you..

1. use stateful instead of stateless so that you can rebuild entire Ui by setState on adding number to list
2. instead of future builder use ListView.builder which use control's RxList number to display data and when adding number into a list. listview will be rebuild if it is wrapped with Obx.
3. use dummy variable in your controller which keep changes on adding number and use this dummy variable inside your future builder as key to rebuild it..here future builder must be wrapped with Obx.

here is code for it...

add RxBool refreshData to your controller

```
class DataController extends GetxController {
  RxBool isLoading = false.obs;
RxBool refreshData=true.obs;
// ADD ABOVE LINE IN YOUR CODE
 

  Future<List<int>> fetchData() async {
    try {
      isLoading.value = true;
      final data = numbers;//numbers is a list[int] stored in different file
      return data;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Something wrong');
      return [];
    } finally {
      isLoading.value = false;
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
Expanded(
            child:  Obx(
                ()=>FutureBuilder(
key:Key(controller.refreshData.value.toString(),
//ADD ABOVE LINE IN YOUR CODE
               future: controller.fetchData(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
```

and finally toggle refreshData value when adding number

```
SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final num = Random().nextInt(1000);
                numbers.add(num);
 controller.refreshData.toggle();
//ADD ABOVE LINE IN YOUR CODE

              },
              child: const Text('Add Number'),
            ))
```

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that the FutureBuilder updates when data is added or deleted, you can make use of a StatefulWidget along with a setState call.

```
class YourWidget extends StatefulWidget {
@override
 _YourWidgetState createState() => _YourWidgetState();
}

class _YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> {
     final controller = Get.put(DataController());

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Obx(
          () => FutureBuilder(
            future: controller.fetchData(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              // Your existing code here
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 100,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            final num = Random().nextInt(1000);
            numbers.add(num);
            setState(() {}); // Trigger rebuild
          },
          child: Text('Add Number'),
        ),
      ),
    ],),);
   }
 }
```

by calling "setState" after adding a number, you will trigger a rebuild of that widget, which wil subsequently trigger the FutureBuilder to evaluate again its future, resultin in fetching updated data. your UI will reflect the changes made to the numbers list.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GetX to manage your state, you should know the 3 options to do that (you can see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74320029/which-are-the-situation-to-use-getbuilder-obx-or-getx-in-flutter)).

Here is how you can change your code to make a dynamic list using Get:

- You have a loading state in your controller, so you can use that to show a loading widget and remove the FutureBuilder (ps: this is a option, you can use both either, you can learn more about FutureBuilder [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)).
- You want to watch a list change, so we can make a observableList inside your controller and watch the changes (you can see about reactive state in the [getx oficial documentation](https://chornthorn.github.io/getx-docs/docs/state/reactive-state)).
- Now we need to create a function that will update the list, so we can call the function in the add number button.

Now this should work.

View:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final controller = Get.put(DataController());
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Obx(
            () => controller.isLoading.value
                ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                : ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: controller.numbers.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final data = controller.numbers[index];
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(data.toString()),
                      );
                    }),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final num = Random().nextInt(1000);
                controller.addNumber(num);
              },
              child: const Text('Add Number'),
            ))
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Controller:

```
class DataController extends GetxController {
  RxBool isLoading = true.obs;
  RxList<int> numbers = <int>[].obs;

  @override
  onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    fetchData();
  }

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    try {
      isLoading.value = true;
      numbers.value = [1, 2, 3];
    } catch (e) {
      print('Something wrong');
    } finally {
      isLoading.value = false;
    }
  }

  void addNumber(int number) {
    numbers.add(number);
  }
}
```